# 414 (Request-Uri Too Long) on azure, Ajax call, data contains URLs to file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, azure, http-post

I get 414 (Request-Uri Too Long) error for the following ajax call on Azure.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/Test/TestView",
            type:"POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(
            {
                source : 'test',
                FileInfo: FileInfo                    
            }),                
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
            proccessData: false,
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#body').html(data);
        });
```

Where FileInfo is array of URL and filename for the file on the server.

Example of FileInfo data:

[{name : "test1",

path : "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test1-20170831141032-f5a38pbm70831141032-f5a38pbmxuucnlh4suvy8q/003119f4-55c2-4e40-a9d4-9781761c7115/test1.data?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=V25sQDRCxW%2B5Uuj2s49GhkjkmNbzPiOHEn4U0cpIY3U%3D&st=2017-09-22T13%3A13%3A09Z&se=2017-09-22T13%3A28%3A09Z&sp=r" }]

NOTE: this works on locahost the only difference is that the filepath within the FileInfo array is path of directory "C:\ProgramData\Test\Test.data"

I tried adding enctype: "multipart/form-data" it did not work either.

Please advise.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. This may cause the issue.

Please change `proccessData` to `processData`. More details, see [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).